# Why my PyDev can't import mpl_toolkits?

Tags: python, eclipse, matplotlib, pydev

I just installed matplotlib including all the required modules. but when I restarted Eclipse and typed code, it said `Unresolved import: mpl_toolkits`.  (I have tried to reload Python interpreater.

Answer (score 2):

`mpl_toolkits` is a [namespace package](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/#namespace-packages-today). Apparently, PyDev does not [handle namespace packages well](http://sourceforge.net/p/pydev/bugs/1305/). As a workaround I insert `#@UnresolvedImport` after the import. This suppresses the error, but code completions still don't work.